# New entries are on top When bound DGV is filled

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

When I fill my DGV from a bound Access Table, it orders by Primary ID to a point -  I say that because I have 1200 records and the DGV is filled in the following order, assuming we are just looking at the Prim. ID column -
1200
1199
1198
1197
1196
1
2
3
4
.....
1195

using the code below -

```
Me.ClientListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ReportGenieDatabaseDataSet2.ClientList)
```

Sorry if this is vague but it's all I got. I hope to be able to order by descending ID - just like the Access table shows.

Also when I look up the .Last value it reads the "1195"

Comment: I ran the "compact and repair" option in MS Access - this resolved my issue - DGV now shows all records 1 - 1200 in order by ID, just like the Access table. Now to find out why that is.... My guess, from little experience, is that I forgot to close a row somewhere down the line but I don't know if this would cause the problem.. Any direction would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There is no order in a table. You can often find from one query to the next, records will be returned in different orders. You MUST thus use a SQL statement to set the order of the data returned. It is likely now you are using some SQL statement to retrieve this data – simply all a ORDER BY clause to that sql.

Comment: I'm recreating the whole Access table in my DGV, using the "Add Project Data Source" option - I used only the code provide by Visual Studio, from what I've seen it seems to always recreate the Access table as it is represented if you were to open it in MS Access, if this is not the case like you're saying - wouldn't it then read that the 1200th record was the last? When I call the .Last command?  -- Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: As noted, it should in most cases come out the same, but it NOT a given. You MUST specify a order in your query. Keep in mind that often auto numbers can be skipped for various reasons, but then again the auto number is a separate issue from that of database order. Editing of data in that table can cause order to change. This change would not show up in your DGV until you re-loaded. For the most part you likely ok, but order in relational databases is NOT guaranteed, you must set such order to be sure.